# Bhagat Singh's essay - Why I am an atheist? I am looking for official hindu response

Tags: atheism

Bhagat Singh has written an essay - Why I am an atheist. I am looking for official hindu response.

Comment: The official Philosophical Hindu response is that each person is entitled to his opinion (Loko Bhinna Ruchi: ). The official Religious Hindu response is that it is possible to realize God's existence, but impossible to prove God's existence. Since scientists (Lokayata or Materialism philosophy) only believe in things that can be proven (with the help of 5 senses), they do not believe in God (who is beyond 5 senses).

Comment: @ram If you can read the essay and write a response?

Comment: don't have time to read it.. but above is standard response to any atheism argument. Hinduism has given a bunch of steps a person must take to realize God. Hinduism also says that it is impossible to prove God's existence. In other words, I can verify God, but cannot prove Him.

Comment: No offence, what is the question here?

Comment: @severussnape Question is, what is hindu response to Bhagat Singh's essay?

Comment: @person thanks for the response. What do you mean by "hindu response"? Do you mean response from Hindu society? Or any Hindu organisation? Or members of HSE?

Comment: @severussnape I mean response based on hindu scriptures or hindu theologians.

Comment: @person Unfortunately it would be a very broad question. You are a long time member of this site, and you know it has infinite number of answers. My granddad (a priest) would give his response, you (a long time member of HSE) would give your response, Sadhguru would give his response, and so on. So, this question as it stands is opinion based. Maybe you can be more specific. Do you think I am wrong?

Comment: @severussnape If response is based on hindu scriptures, it is ok. I did not understand your point.

Comment: We owe Bhagat Singh no response. Having said that Bhagat Singh was partially a Sikh, and as with many warrior Sikhs he has unwittingly done more for the preservation of Hinduism than, let's say, the vast majority of scriptural absolutists